# kill store procedure execution using command in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am very new to the mysql and i need to kill the store procedure execution by running a command in mysql workbench.
That kill command will be called by an API written in JAVA to kill the store procedure execution.

I have tried to use the

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user <> 'system user';
```

But processlist table is not showing my store procedure .

Can anyone help me ,how to kill the store procedure execution programatically ?

Comment: I would consider "killing a stored procedure" to be a dangerously unreliable and unpredictable thing to do.  I counsel against any such design. *("Killing" anything* is unreliable ...)